# Поиск ошибки в коде

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Помогите найти ошибку, при модерации сообщения если в поле добавить `'` вылетает такая ошибка.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FALSE' WHERE id = '2' LIMIT 1' at line 3
```

**function php**

```
    public function moderate($id, $comment, $moderate, $name = NULL) {
    global $mysql, $langArray;

    $mysql->query("
        UPDATE forum_threads 
        SET name = '".$name."',
            comment = '".$comment."',
            moderate = '".$moderate."'
        WHERE id = '".intval($id)."'
        LIMIT 1
    ");

    return true;
}
```

**php**

```
    if (check_login_bool() && isset($_POST['moderate']) && is_numeric($_POST['moderate']) && isset($_POST['post_message'])) {
            if (isset($_POST['censor_message'])) {
                $censor_message = 'TRUE';
            }
            else {
                $censor_message = 'FALSE';
            }

            if (!isset($_POST['post_name'])) {
                $_POST['post_name'] = NULL;
            }

            $s = $forumClass->moderate($_POST['moderate'], htmlentities($_POST['post_message']), $censor_message, htmlentities($_POST['post_name']));

            if ($s == true) {
                refresh('/forum/thread/' . url($thread[$threadID]['name']) . '/' . $threadID, $langArray['complete_moderate_message'], 'complete');
            }
            else {
                addErrorMessage($s, '', 'error');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё просто используйте `mysqli_real_escape_string` вместо `htmlentities`

```
$s = $forumClass->moderate(
       $_POST['moderate'], 
       mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql,POST['post_message']), 
       $censor_message,  
       mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql,$_POST['post_name'])
     );
```

Comment: Данный способ удаляет данные с таблицы

Comment: @evanto поправил ошибся немного

Comment: @evanto какую библиотеку для sql используешь, модуль точнее?

Comment: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Версия MySQL-клиента: 5.5.44
PHP расширение: mysqli

Comment: @evanto что var_dump() говорит по этому поводу. `var_dump($_POST,mysqli_real_escape_string($mysql,$_POST['post_message']));die();`

Comment: при замене на mysqli_real_escape_string содержимое удаляется, новое не добавить

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35736/discussion-between-naumov-and-evanto).

Comment: "-" так как кастыль

Comment: @Ипатьев где кастыль?

Comment: там же где и в другом ответе

Comment: @Ипатьев в другом ответе предлагают сделать `addcslashes(htmlentities($_POST['post_message']))` да и почитайте документацию по этой функции http://php.net/manual/ru/function.addslashes.php ну и цитата из неё `Для экранирования параметров в базе данных нужно использовать специализированные экранирующие функции СУБД`

Comment: Я не только читал документацию. А еще и понимаю, что там написано. Твое решение *ничем* не лучше addslashes. То есть, оно представляет из себя такой же точно костыль.

Comment: @Ипатьев Может приведёшь тогда ответ со своим решением? может оно лучше окажеться? Аргументы где?

Comment: Во-первых, нет смысла писать ответ на вопрос-оффтопик с ужепринятым ответом. Во-вторых, нет смысле что-то доказывать человеку, который считает что и так уже всё знает. Но чисто в плане благотворительности, попробуй почитать то что написано по ссылке http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string

Comment: @Ипатьев `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_message']) вот так все работает большое спасибо за расширение моих знаний` так мы к ней пришли, в чём проблема предложить какой то ответ более лучший по вашему мнению?

Comment: Ой. А *эту-то* ты функцию откуда взял? Немедленно положи на место и больше никогда не трогай!

Comment: @Ипатьев так он использует mysql а не mysqli... я вижу у вас нет никаких аргументов

Comment: Это естественно. потому что я не утруждаю себя ими. По причинам, изложенным выше. Я дал тебе ссылку для чисто самообразования. Но без особой, впрочем, надежды.

Comment: @Ипатьев закончим разговор... Так как вижу у нас у обоих проблемы с самообразованием.... и это не тема вопроса.